# Object passed to a controller via a route 'resolve:' directive is erring with an 'Unknown Provider' message

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following code in my main JS:

```
app.service('portfolioData', function($http, LoginData, Config) {
    return {
        load: function() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: getHostnamePort(Config) + '/rest/api/property/list',
                headers: { 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'x-api-token': LoginData.apiToken,
                    'x-api-user': LoginData.apiUser
                }
            }).then( function successCallback( response ) {
                console.log( "Portfolio loaded" );
                return response.data;
            }, function errorCallback ( response ) {
                console.log( "Portfolio load FAILED" );
                console.log( response.status );
                if ( response.status == '401' )
                    $scope.failureMessage = "Unauthorised. Please Login in.";
                return null;
            });
        }
    };
});
...
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
...
"http://xxxx/~matthew/view/portfolio.view", resolve: { portfolio: function(portfolioData) { return portfolioData.load(); } }});
});
```

And my target Controller (declared in the portfolio.view) is declared thus:

```
app.controller('PortfolioCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http', '$mdDialog', 'LoginData', 'pageData', 'Config', 'portfolio', function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog, LoginData, pageData, Config, portfolio) {

pageData.setTitle( "Portfolio" );
$scope.portfolio = portfolio.result;
$scope.portfolioFailed = false;
```

The resolve is working correctly at the route end, and I can see the back-end calls getting the data, but when it goes to render the view, I get:

[image]

I know there may be some kind of scoping issue, but the documentation is vague, and an example I'm following (https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx) suggests I've set it up it correctly.

Comment: Where have you defined your controller? In HTML view using `ng-controller` or in state configuration using `controller:` key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a catch here. You must be defining the controller in your HTML view as `ng-controller="PortfolioCtrl"` but `ui-router` will not inject those `resolve`d dependencies if you define your controller via `ng-controller`.

So you need to define your controller in the state configuration only:

```
.state('xyz', {
    templateURL: "http://xxxx/~matthew/view/portfolio.view",
    resolve: {
        portfolio: function(portfolioData) { return portfolioData.load(); }
    },
    controller: 'PortfolioCtrl' // <<=== you need to define it here
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the missing piece. However, the actual template isn't rendering at all. No messages, just silently ignored. The data arrived, but I suspect there needs to be some kind of signal to render the template?

Comment: Ignore my last. I solved it. I had the controller declaration within the resolve section... Oops. :)